# Invalid api path

Tags: android, magento, soap

Hi I created custom api for user login, its working fine. But I tried to create api to get category images. its giving Invalid api path for in built magento api.
Below are the configuration files I am using.

Config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mycustom_Masterapi>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Mycustom_Masterapi>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <masterapi>
        <class>Mycustom_Masterapi_Model</class>
      </masterapi>
    </models>
    <helpers>
      <masterapi>
        <class>Mycustom_Masterapi_Helper</class>
      </masterapi>
    </helpers>
  </global>
</config>
```

api.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <api>

    <resources>

      <masterapi_loginmodel translate="title" module="masterapi">
        <model>masterapi/loginmodel_api</model>
        <title>Demo Custommoduleapi API</title>
        <acl>masterapi/loginmodel</acl>
        <methods>
         <!-- <list translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>List of masterapi</title>
            <method>clogin</method>
          </list> -->
          <customerlogin translate="title" module="masterapi">
           <title>List of masterapi</title>
          </customerlogin>

        </methods>
      </masterapi_loginmodel>

       <masterapi_category translate="title" module="masterapi">
        <model>masterapi/category_api</model>
        <title>Demo category API</title>
        <acl>masterapi/category</acl>
        <methods>
         <!-- <list translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>List of masterapi</title>
            <method>clogin</method>
          </list> -->
          <getID translate="title" module="masterapi">
           <title>List of category</title>
          </getID>

        </methods>
      </masterapi_category>


    </resources>


    <resources_alias>
      <loginmodel>masterapi_loginmodel</loginmodel>
      <category>masterapi_category</category>
    </resources_alias>

    <v2>
      <resources_function_prefix>
         <loginmodel>masterapiLoginmodel</loginmodel>
          <category>masterapiCategory</category>
      </resources_function_prefix>
    </v2>

    <acl>
      <resources>
        <masterapi translate="title" module="masterapi">
          <title>Loginmodel</title>
          <sort_order>5</sort_order>
          <loginmodel translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>loginmodel data</title>
          </loginmodel>

           <category translate="title" module="masterapi">
            <title>loginmodel data</title>
          </category>

        </masterapi>

      </resources>
    </acl>
  </api>
</config>
```

wsdl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
  xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">

  <types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
      <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      <complexType name="fieldInfo">
        <sequence>
          <element name="entity_id" type="xsd:string"/>
          <element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        </sequence>
      </complexType>
      <complexType name="fieldInfoArray">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:fieldInfo[]" />
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>


      <!---Declare our types-->
            <complexType name="catalogCategoryID">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="category_id" type="xsd:string" />
                    <element name="category_name" type="xsd:string" />
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
       <!---Declare our input and output parameters-->
            <element name="catalogCategoryGetIDRequestParam">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="category_name" type="xsd:string" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <element name="catalogCategoryGetIDResponseParam">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
            <!---here we use the type we declared earlier as our output parameter-->
                        <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="result" type="typens:catalogCategoryID" />
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>
            <!---Boohoo-->


    </schema>
  </types>

  <message name="masterapiLoginmodelListRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="user" type="xsd:string" />
     <part name="pass" type="xsd:string" /> 
  </message>

  <message name="masterapiLoginmodelListResponse">
    <part name="customlogin" type="xsd:string" />
  </message>



  <portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <operation name="masterapiLoginmodelCustomerlogin">
      <documentation>List of masterapi</documentation>
      <input message="typens:masterapiLoginmodelListRequest" />
      <output message="typens:masterapiLoginmodelListResponse" />
    </operation>

    <operation name="masterapiCategoryGetID">
      <documentation>List of masterapi</documentation>
      <input message="typens:masterapiCategoryCustomerloginRequest" />
      <output message="typens:catalogCategoryGetIDResponse" />
    </operation>

  </portType>


   <message name="masterapiCategoryCustomerloginRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    <part name="category_name" type="xsd:string" />

  </message>

   <message name="catalogCategoryGetIDResponse">
        <part name="parameters" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>


  <binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <operation name="masterapiLoginmodelCustomerlogin">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
      <input>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </output>
    </operation>

     <operation name="masterapiCategoryGetID">
      <soap:operation soapAction="urn:{{var wsdl.handler}}Action" />
      <input>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body namespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
      </output>
    </operation>

  </binding>



  <service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
    <port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
      <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

my php file: Api.php

```
<?php
// app/code/local/Envato/Customlogin/Model/Loginmodel/Api.php
class Mycustom_Masterapi_Model_Category_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{
  /**
 * retrieves Category ID based on category name
 *
 */
 public function getID($category_name){

 $category_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->loadByAttribute('name',$category_name);
 $result = array();
 $result['category_id'] = $category_model->getId();
 $result['category_name'] = $category_name;

 return $category_name;
 }
}
```

I followed this link [this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-api-in-magento-part-one--cms-23785). I made changes for user log in its working great. But I want customized api to get Category Images along category tree.
But when I call "catalogCategoryTree" using soap its giving as "Invalid Api Path". Please let me know what mistake In the configuration files.

Comment: can u try changing the method name. i think getId is reserved method name ?

Comment: Reena Parekh thank you for your reply. I tried but not working by changing the name but same error "Invalid api path" when I call "catalogCategoryTree".

Comment: can u share how u r calling it ?

Comment: request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "catalogCategoryTree");
    request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId_magento);
    env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    androidHttpTransport.call("", env);

    Log.e("object", sessionid.toString());